# EF Core 5 Many-to-Many relation - Change the Navigation key

Tags: c#, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-5.0

I have two entities with many to many relationships in EF Core 5 and I am using fluent API to set the relationship.

```
public class Framework
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Path> Paths { get; set; } = new List<Path>();
}

public class Path
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Framework> Frameworks { get; set; } = new List<Framework>();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
      base.OnModelCreating(builder);

      builder.Entity<Framework>()
          .HasMany(x => x.Paths)
          .WithMany(x => x.Frameworks)
          .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
              "FrameworkPaths",
              x => x.HasOne<Path>().WithMany(),
              x => x.HasOne<Framework>().WithMany(),
          );
```

It is working fine and data is being added in the many to many table (which has these columns *FrameworksId*, *PathsId*)

But now I want to change the Property name in **Path** entity from *Frameworks* to *LinkedFrameworks* as

```
public IList<Framework> LinkedFrameworks { get; set; } = new List<Framework>();
```

How can I use this new property name *LinkedFrameworks* instead of *Framework* in CRUD operations of entites?

Comment: Can't you just rename the navigation property and test if it works. If it doesn't try to run `Add-Migration`, update the database with the new migration and test again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was achieved by adding the .HasForeignKey() in usingEntity

```
builder.Entity<Framework>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Paths)
                .WithMany(x => x.LinkedFrameworks)  //Change the name here
                .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                    "FrameworkPaths",
                    x => x.HasOne<Path>().WithMany(),
                    x => x.HasOne<Framework>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("FrameworksId")); //tell the EF about the Foreign Key
```